# Javascript error when calling javascript library function

Tags: javascript

I have been developing a javascript library called TechX. Here is the code:

```
(function(){
        function tex(s){
            return new tex.init(s);
        };
        //declare the init selector function
        tex.init = function(s){
            if(!s){
                return this;
            }
            else{
                this.length = 1;
                if (typeof s === "object"){
                    this[0] = s;
                }
                else if(typeof s === "string"){
                    var obj;
                    obj = document.querySelector(s);
                    this[0] = obj;
                }
                return this;
            }
        }
        tex.prototype = {
            dit : function(){
                this.innerHTML = 'Hi?!?!?!';
            }
        };
        window.tex = tex;
})();
```

In my body I have this script to test it out:

```
<input type="button" id="inpt" value="click"></input>
<div id="test"></div>
<script>
var inn = document.getElementById("inpt");
inn.onclick = function(){
    tex('#test').dit();
};
</script>
```

When I load the page there are no errors, but when I click the button I get an error that says, "`'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'tex('#test').dit();')`."

Does anyone know what I have done wrong in my code? How can I fix the error? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like the issue is that `tex("#test")` returns a `text.init` object, but `.dit()` is a method on `tex`, not on `tex.init` so there's no method `.dit()` to execute.

Perhaps you want to change this:

```
tex.prototype = {...}
```

to this:

```
tex.init.prototype = {...}
```

so the `.dit()` method will be on the type of object you're actually creating.

---

Also, I think this:

```
        dit : function(){
            this.innerHTML = 'Hi?!?!?!';
        }
```

needs to be this:

```
        dit : function(){
            this[0].innerHTML = 'Hi?!?!?!';
        }
```

or, if you intend for it to work like jQuery, you'd have to iterate over all the contained objects like this:

```
        dit : function(){
            for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
                this[i].innerHTML = 'Hi?!?!?!';
            }
        }
```

Comment: Ok, I tried that and there was no error, but nothing happened to the div.

Comment: @CodeApprentice - doesn't `this.innerHTML = 'Hi?!?!?!';` need to be `this[0].innerHTML = 'Hi?!?!?!';` or if you're doing it jQuery like, then you need to apply the method to all the objects in the array.

Comment: I would like to do this the jQuery way, but how would I apply the method to all the objects?